# SQL query to compare tables and only return differences

Tags: mysql, sql-server, compare

I have two tables. The first table is the "Raw" table, and houses the original record when it was submitted (so it never changes, just gets additional records). Then I have another table that has the "updated" data (so it has the same number of records, with same columns, but the values may be different).

I want to run a SQL query that will compare the two tables. For the output, I want a new table that lists the PK of the row that had a changed value. But I only want to return the new value.

My end goal is to be able to say "within column A, we had x amount of changes. Of the changes for column A, the value we most often updated to was fill_in_the_blank."

If I use this basic query:

```
(Select * from [Test Database].dbo.[Raw Data]
except
select * from [Test Database Second].dbo.[Clean Data]
union all
Select * from [Test Database Second].dbo.[Clean Data]
except
select * from [Test Database].dbo.[Raw Data])
```

I get the rows back that have different fields, but don't know what value/column changed.

Comment: when you say `value/column changed`, with respect to what does it change. do you have any key defined in both the tables which help you identify that the key remains the same but other column changes ?

Comment: So each table has a column named "ID" that contains unique IDs/is our PK. Each PK exists only once within each table. There are also typically about 500 rows.